# npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I can't seem to understand why this error is happening. I am trying to create a new react-native project with another already created and in a different directory which is not lower in the directory tree than the other installation. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the node which I thought might be the issue. I used brew doctor and removed a previous install of homebrew which I had in `usr/local/includes`

I'm trying to get a clean install of React-native but It appears I can't do so.

Thank you for any help.

This is the error I keep getting

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.67.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@6.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/cli@"^6.0.0" from react-native@0.67.4
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.69.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! react-native@"0.69.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     react-native@"0.69.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/Name/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Name/.npm/_logs/2022-07-14T06_15_09_791Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same issue as yours. To fix the error.

Open cli then type: `open /Users/Name/.npm`  then delete folders _cacache, _logs, _npx.

After deleting those folders I'm able to install new React Native project.

FOR WINDOWS:
C:\Users\trung\AppData\Name\npm-cache

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I had wiped my hard drive to fix it and do a fresh install and I'm having no problems now. That might have worked so thank you for the response anyway.

Comment: how about windows users?

Answer (score 21):

Add `--legacy-peer-deps` to the end of the command

```
--legacy-peer-deps
```

More infos:

Peer dependencies are a type of dependency that a package requires in order to work properly, but that is not automatically installed when the package is installed. Instead, the package assumes that the peer dependency is already installed in the project's environment. The `--legacy-peer-deps` option instructs npm to use the old behavior and not automatically install peer dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: open /Users/Name/.npm

Step 2: To view hidden folders on Mac press `Cmd + Shift + .(dot)`

Step 3: Delete folders _cacache, _logs, _npx

[image: /Users/Name/.npm]

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows Users:**

Open `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\npm-cache` then delete folders `_cacache`,  `_logs`, `_npx`

After deleting those folders, I can install a new React Native project on my windows pc.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply run `npm cache clear -f` and then install again